# Shorter notation for a two column table?

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a document containing a lot of tables, layed out like in the following Word mockup:

[image: Example table]

While I think I could use the `tabular` enviroment to create this, this would be quite messy.

Ideally, I'd like to use something like

```
\begin{funkytable}
\entry{Normal entry}
With some text aside.
\entry{A very long entry here, requiring a break}
Some more text, aligned with the botton of the text on the right, expanding downward.

A new paragraph here. There are none such for the right column.
\entry{Another normal entry}
\entry{And another one.}
Nothing in the line above.
\end{funkytable}
```

Could you point me to a package, where this is easier accomplished, or help me with an idea on how to create my own commands/environments to generate this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `enumitem` package. Of course, in the unlikely case the label is longer than the description, you'll need to manually add space to separate the items to solve the issue (within reason). Do it by adding `\\\mbox{}` at the end of the offending longer label's description (not the label's end).

[image: figure 1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\strut\smash{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}}
\setlist[itemize]{style=multiline,leftmargin=5cm, align=parright}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[font=\bfseries]
    \item[Normal entry] With some text aside.
    \item[A very long entry here, requiring a break] Some more text, aligned with the botton of the text on the right, expanding downward.\\\\A new paragraph here. There are none such for the right column.
    \item[Another normal entry]
    \item[And another one.] Nothing in the line above.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: there's a paragraph break missing in the right-hand column.  (as well as some vertical spacing.)  also, compare your left/right column alignment with the original.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I included the paragraph break, but I'm not sure what you mean about the alignment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton means to use `[b]` not `[t]` to match `requiring a break` aligning with `Some more` but I can't believe the OP really wants that (even though that's what's shown:-)

Comment: I really want "requiring a break" to be aligned with "Some more". Thats one requirement that make it difficult for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tabular`-like environment for `funkytable` that uses [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\newcommand{\insertnewline}{}
\newcommand{\entry}[1]{\insertnewline #1 &}
\newenvironment{funkytable}
  {\gdef\insertnewline{\gdef\insertnewline{\\}}%
   \noindent
   \tabularx{\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft\bfseries\arraybackslash}b{.3\linewidth}X}
  }
  {\endtabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{funkytable}
  \entry{Normal entry}
  With some text aside.
  \entry{A very long entry here, requiring a break}
  Some more text, aligned with the botton of the text on the right, expanding downward.

  A new paragraph here. There are none such for the right column.
  \entry{Another normal entry}
  \entry{And another one.}
  Nothing in the line above.
\end{funkytable}

\end{document}
```

Of course, this structure will not break across the page boundary.

Comment: This looks good! Just a question, what is the purpose of the insertnewline command?